# Angular MVC Newbie: How can I move view content from controller to a view template?

Tags: angularjs

I have an app that is implementing Google Maps. I am dynamically generating map markers from a JSON model, with a function within the controller. The function is called from within a for loop (which loops through the JSON content) in the controller. Here is the line that sets the html for each entry in the JSON:

```
marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '<br />' + '<a href="tel:+1' + info.phone + '">' + info.phone + '</div>';
```

This is just the beginning of what I am going to end up with; there is much more html.

My question is: Is there a way to create an html template and move what is become a partial out of my controller?
What is the proper MCV way of handling this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This code completely goes against the philosophy of angular. You should put your view directly into the html, and make use of the 'double-binding' mechanism in Angular to keep the dynamic parts up to date.

So your html (the view) should look something like this:

```
<div class="infoWindowContent" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">{{ctrl.desc}} 
  <a ng-href="tel:+1{{ctrl.info.phone}}">{{ctrl.info.phone}}
</div>
```

And on the controller object you should define the info and desc variables:

```
this.info = { ... } ;
```

Now whenever the controller modifies the vars the view is automatically updated. You can also use ng-model to make those vars updateable in the view, and then they are automatically updated in the controller. This is why it's called two-way binding.

Comment: Thanks. But, how do I then pull the html into the marker.content variable? This is not my main html, it is Google Maps marker code pulled into my main html. i.e. someone clicks on a map marker, a box built with marker.content pops up.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your question a little bit with some relevant code or even a reproducable snippet on https://jsfiddle.net/ ? I don't really follow what you are doing here.

Comment: I cannot place working code on jsfiddle; Google Maps requires a site specific API key.

To reword what I am doing: I have a lot of html that is going to end up in my model - on marker.content. Is there a way to create a template / partial to hold that html, then call the template into marker.content?

I did put all of my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/jrcreasy/mnnmndyu/ But, the API key issue prevents it from working.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you'll want some type of include based on your question/comments.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="map">    
    <div class="infoWindowContent" ng-controller="googleMaps as gm">
        {{gm.desc}}
        <a ng-href="tel:+1'{{gm.desc}}">{{gm.phone}}</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then you could inject based on some parameter:

```
<div ng-if="showMap" ng-include="'map'"></div>
```

Instead you could write a function to get the html and the data once the element has been clicked and inject it into the page at that time.